# NodeJS config default environment

Tags: node.js, configuration, config

Is it possible to change the default environment used by [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)?

The default environment is 'development' but I would like to change that to another value (in a way that also changes the configuration file load order accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Three options :

- Set `NODE_ENV` environment variable. ( eg : `export NODE_ENV=prod` )
- Passing env in command line ( eg : `NODE_ENV=prod node myapp.js` )
- Set environment directly in your code

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = "prod";
const config = require('config');
```

I recommend first option !

Comment: The first two solutions are not really setting the default value (since the default value is the values that is used when NODE_ENV is not set). The third solution generally works, but I ran into other problems (for example, when NODE_ENV was originally undefined it later had the string value 'undefined' for some reason). 
As conclusion: there may be no proper elegant way to set the default environment, so I made it work with the default value 'development'.

But nonetheless, thank you for you answer!

Comment: If your NODE_ENV originally works and then later it is 'undefined' that doesn't sound like a problem with the default environment.